# Getting name and email from contact list is very slow

Tags: android, contacts, autocompletetextview, android-cursor

I'm implementing an AutoCompleteTextView and I need Name and E-Mail of all my contacts.
I found this snippet that I'm running asynchronously but it's very slow.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

if (cur.getCount() > 0) {               
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {                  
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));                   
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null); 

            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 

                String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    autoCompleteAdapter.add(name + " - " + email);
            }

            emailCur.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm performing a sort of inner query and I think that's the problem. Is there a way to tune it and make it faster?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working ?

Comment: The outer `if (cur.getCount() > 0)` is redundant and may be removed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
};

...

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        final int contactIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID);
        final int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
        long contactId;
        String displayName, address;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            contactId = cursor.getLong(contactIdIndex);
            displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
            address = cursor.getString(emailIndex);
            ...
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

few notes:

- use just `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI` to get information you need, see [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html) for information what columns you can query
- use projection to get only those columns you really need, you save some memory and increase query performance
- get column indexes only once, just before the while cycle

Comment: how can i read whole v-card in efficient way it means to read whole address book.

Answer (score 6):

You should not query directly the [ContactsContract.Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)

Make just **one** query on the [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html) with the email data kind.

The [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html) inherits a lot of other interfaces that you can use to build your projection. (see inherited constants from the documentation)

For example :

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;

[...]

public static final String[]  EMAILS_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    Email._ID,
    Email.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
    Email.ADDRESS
};
```

to be used with the

```
Email.CONTENT_URI
```

You can retrieve a lot of information (such as user id, user display name ...) directly from the email data kind.

**EDIT:**

I just realized you're trying to build an AutoCompleteTextView.

You should override the `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` method and the `convertToString` of your CursorAdapter and use the [Email.CONTENT_FILTER_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html#CONTENT_FILTER_URI)

I **really strongly** suggest you to take a look at the **ApiDemo samples**.

Especially the **AutoComplete4.java** sample that you can find **[HERE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/AutoComplete4.java)**.

Comment: Thanks Timothée, your explanation is very well done. Too bad I can't mark both answers as correct. I think that biegleux's answer is very good (works incredibly well) for other users looking for a quick snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver(); 
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, "HAS_PHONE_NUMBER <> 0", null, null); 

if (cursor!= null) 
{ 
    final int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME); 
    final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER); 
    final int idIndex= cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID); 
    String displayName, number = null, idValue; 

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
        idValue= cursor.getString(idIndex);

        Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, "contact_id = '" + idValue + "'", null, null);
        phones.moveToFirst();

        try 
        {
            number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
        }
        catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
        }

        phones.close();
        userList.add(new ContactModel(displayName, number, null));
    }
}
```