# Xamarin.Mobile Contacts API takes up a lot of time while fetching contacts?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin.mobile

I'm using Xamarin.Mobile Component for Android to fetch contacts using the code:

```
var book = new AddressBook (Activity) {PreferContactAggregation = true};
var contData = data.Data;
var cur = Activity.ManagedQuery (contData, null, null, null, null);
Contact myContact = null;
var lookupKeyList = new List<string> ();
while (cur.MoveToNext ()) {
lookupKeyList.Add (cur.GetString (cur.GetColumnIndexContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.LookupKey)));
}

myContact = book.Where (c => c.Id == lookupKeyList [0]).First ();
```

This code is part of picking a contact from the phone book and receiving the data on OnActivityResult method.
Unfortunately, this code is taking up too much time on some devices and is instantaneous on others. I guess its related to Contact Aggregation but I am not sure. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an Android issue, not necessarily a Xamarin issue. Take a look at the question [Getting name and email from contact list is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109391/getting-name-and-email-from-contact-list-is-very-slow). One of the things this answer does is use a Projection in the query to get all the columns in one go.

Comment: I could use a projection here but I need to differentiate data received into Work Phone, Home Phone, Work Email, Home Email etc. In the code I am using above, I just get the LookupKey field and use it to get contacts from the Xamarin.Mobile Contacts API which easily provides me an object to differentiate data into the fields I mentioned above.