# Android ContactsContract with AutocompleteTextview too slow

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, contactscontract

Am trying to use the `ContactsProvider` with my `AutoCompleteTextview` using a method that fetches the data (name and phone number) and stores them in a list. As expected, this method will always take time to complete as am calling the method in the `onCreateView` method of my `Fragment` class.

This is the method:

```
...
ArrayList<String> phoneValues;
ArrayList<String> nameValues;
...

private void readContactData() {

    try {

        /*********** Reading Contacts Name And Number **********/

        String phoneNumber = "";
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity()
                .getContentResolver();

        //Query to get contact name

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver
                .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        // If data data found in contacts
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            int k=0;
            String name = "";

            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {

                String id = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                //Check contact have phone number
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cursor
                                .getString(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                {

                    //Create query to get phone number by contact id
                    Cursor pCur = contentResolver
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?",
                                    new String[] { id },
                                    null);
                    int j=0;

                    while (pCur
                            .moveToNext())
                    {
                        // Sometimes get multiple data
                        if(j==0)
                        {
                            // Get Phone number
                            phoneNumber =""+pCur.getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            // Add contacts names to adapter
                            autocompleteAdapter.add(name);

                            // Add ArrayList names to adapter
                            phoneValues.add(phoneNumber.toString());
                            nameValues.add(name.toString());

                            j++;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }  // End while loop
                    pCur.close();
                } // End if

            }  // End while loop

        } // End Cursor value check
        cursor.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("AutocompleteContacts","Exception : "+ e);
    }


}
```

Am sure there is a better way to accomplish this, but this method works and the suggestions are presented when I type into the `AutocompleteTextview`. Am just worried about the time it takes. How can I accomplish this without populating an `ArrayList`?
I have looked at this question: [Getting name and email from contact list is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109391/getting-name-and-email-from-contact-list-is-very-slow) and applied the suggestions in the answer to my code, but now nothing is suggested when I type.How can I improve the performance of my current code?

Comment: "How can I accomplish this without populating an arrayList?" use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` also, how long does it take? for how many contacts?

Comment: Data set is independent of view hierarchy. Set retain instance to true and get your data in `onCreate` asynchronously via a `CursorLoader`.

Comment: @pskink when I click on a button to navigate to the fragment, it takes about 8 seconds to navigate to that fragment

Comment: how many contacts do you have?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how many contacts" but am guessing it's fetching all the contacts on my phone? Which are like 192

Comment: @EugenPechanec could you please go into a little more detail on this?

Comment: as i said, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` here http://pastebin.com/fdg3QmAq you have magic 17 lines of complete working code

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have implemented `AutoCompleteTextView` and it works fine for me ..

```
  final AutoCompleteTextView act=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
         ArrayList<String> alContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
         ArrayList<String> alNames= new ArrayList<String>();

ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{

    do
    {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{ id }, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String contactName=pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                alNames.add(contactName);
                alContacts.add(contactNumber);
                break;
            }
            pCur.close();
        }

    } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
}


String[] array=new String[alNames.size()];
array=(String[]) alNames.toArray(array);
ArrayAdapter<String> myArr= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,array);
act.setAdapter(myArr);
act.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: And where did you place this code? In your onCreate() ?

Comment: Oh.. Are u getting any error? No idea why its not working for u.. For me it still works..

Comment: No errors, but the autocomplete suggestion does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the slow response by placing the method inside an AsynTask.

```
 public class AutocompleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    public Void doInBackground(Void...params) {

        try {

            /*********** Reading Contacts Name And Number **********/

            String phoneNumber = "";
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity()
                    .getContentResolver();

            //Query to get contact name

            Cursor cursor = contentResolver
                    .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null);

            // If data data found in contacts
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                int k=0;
                String name = "";

                while (cursor.moveToNext())
                {
            //...Rest of the same code as above
```

and then calling this in my onCreateView():

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 

  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
  new AutocompleteAsyncTask().execute();
   return rootView;
}
```

Now the task of inflating my view and fetching the data are separated into two different threads.

The `CursorLoader` option mentioned by `Eugen Pechanec` is kinda the best option, so I'll update this answer with that option when I can.

Comment: as i said, use SimpleCursorAdapter here http://pastebin.com/fdg3QmAq you have magic 17 lines of complete working code

Comment: Tried it.Am getting an error : `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` but when I comment out the second line of the code, it works but a strange text is returned: `android.content.contentresolver$CursorWrapperInner@41b78fd8`

Comment: dont comment the second line,  just use one setContentView in your onCreate method

Comment: That was why I commented the second line.To use just one.If I leave the second line and comment out the default setContentView method, I also get an error

Comment: just add my code to an **empty** onCreate method (keep  super.onCreate only)

Comment: Activity#onCreate() ? you dont call it, its called by the system

Comment: create an Activity with empty onCreate method, add super.onCreate and then my code

Comment: Sorry,am away from my computer right now.Will give you a feedback ASAP